# Can we show legends in a popup instead in the chart container with Highcharts.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, highcharts, legend

I am new to highcharts. The chart legends are shown below the chart which takes too much space. Can we implement something like a popup in which those legends will be placed. We will add a button in chart container, on click of it we will open this popup.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but you have to create your own custom legend, for example:

```
            load: function() {
                var chart = this,
                    legendSymbol;

                $(chart.series).each(function(i, serie) {
                    legendSymbol = "<svg width='20' height='15'>" + serie.legendSymbol.element.outerHTML + "</svg>";
                    $('<span class="customLegendItem">' + legendSymbol + serie.name + '</span>').click(function() {
                        serie.visible ? serie.hide() : serie.show();
                    }).appendTo('#legend');
                });

                $('#toggleLegend').on('click', function() {
                    $('#legend').toggle();
                });
            }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w3g0fv75/